# i need all my html table rows to sumit to database

Tags: php, sql

I want to submit all rows, when I submit. Currently only one row is submitting.
This is how I post to the database:

```
<?php
$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}
if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "pro_forms_in_form")) {
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO ho_add_stock_proforma (supplier, inv_no, `day`, `month`, `year`, product_name, descrpt, qty, cost, hawker, wholesale, retail, total) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
  GetSQLValueString($_POST['supplier'], "text"),
  GetSQLValueString($_POST['inv_no'], "int"),
  GetSQLValueString($_POST['day'], "int"),
  GetSQLValueString($_POST['month'], "int"),
  GetSQLValueString($_POST['year'], "int"),
  GetSQLValueString($_POST['product_name'], "text"),
  GetSQLValueString($_POST['descrpt'], "text"),
  GetSQLValueString($_POST['qty'], "text"),
  GetSQLValueString($_POST['cost'], "text"),
  GetSQLValueString($_POST['hawker'], "text"),
  GetSQLValueString($_POST['wholesale'], "text"),
  GetSQLValueString($_POST['retail'], "text"),
  GetSQLValueString($_POST['total'], "text"));
  mysql_select_db($database_universal, $universal);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $universal) or die(mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db($database_universal, $universal);
$query_Creditors = "SELECT company_name FROM ho_add_creditors";
$Creditors = mysql_query($query_Creditors, $universal) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Creditors = mysql_fetch_assoc($Creditors);
$totalRows_Creditors = mysql_num_rows($Creditors);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<!-- and this part help with adding more table rows -->

<script type="text/javascript">
function addRow(ho_add_stock_proforma) {            
  var table = document.getElementById(ho_add_stock_proforma);            
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;           
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);            
  var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;            
  for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {                 
    var newcell = row.insertCell(i);                 
    newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;                
    //alert(newcell.childNodes);                
    switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {                    
      case "text":                            
        newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";                           
        break;                    
      case "checkbox":                            
        newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;                           
        break;                   
      case "select-one":                            
        newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;                           
        break;               
    }           
  }       
}        
function deleteRow(ho_add_stock_proforma) {           
  try {            
    var table = document.getElementById(ho_add_stock_proforma);           
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;             
    for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {               
      var row = table.rows[i];               
      var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];               
      if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {                   
        if(rowCount <= 1) {                       
          alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");                       
          break;                   
        }                    
        table.deleteRow(i);                    
        rowCount--;                   
        i--;               
      }              
    }            
  }catch(e) 
  {               
    alert(e);           
  } 
  getValues();
}        

</script>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="wrap">
  <form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="POST" name="pro_forms_in_form">

    <!-- and this is my html table -->

    <table width="666" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" class="table" id="ho_add_stock_proforma" name="ho_add_stock_proforma">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk" style="width:40px" /></td>


      <td width="122" scope="col">Product Name<input name="product_name" type="text" class="table_fields" id="product_name" /></td>
      <td width="122" scope="col">Description<input name="descrpt" type="text" class="table_fields" id="description" /></td>
      <td width="62" scope="col">Qty<input name="qty" type="text" class="qty" id="qty" onkeyup="getValues()" /></td>
      <td width="62" scope="col">Cost per Piece<input name="cost" type="text" class="price" id="cost" onkeyup="getValues()"/></td>
      <td width="62" scope="col">hawker<input name="hawker" type="text" class="price" id="hawker" /></td>
      <td width="62" scope="col">Wholesale<input name="wholesale" type="text" class="price" id="wholesale" /></td>
      <td width="62" scope="col">Retail<input name="retail" type="text" class="price" id="retail" /></td>
      <td width="349" scope="col">Total<input name="total" type="text" class="price" id="total" onKeyUp="getValues()" /></td>
      <td width="5">  <input name="button" type="button" value="Add" onclick="addRow('ho_add_stock_proforma')" style="width:40px"/></td>
      <td><input name="button"   type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow('ho_add_stock_proforma')" style="width:40px"/></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <input name="submit" type="submit" class="button_submit" value="Submit Form" id="submit" />

  <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="pro_forms_in_form" />
  </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding rows to an HTML Table via Javascript, and then using PHP to add/update the rows in the database, correct?

The new HTML table rows exist only in the browser (you created them client-side via Javascript): the PHP running on the server doesn't know they exist, so it cannot insert/update them in the database.

You will need to generate the new rows of the HTML table server-side and reload the browser page, or else you will need to manually include the new rows in each POST if you generate them client-side.